# How to send SMS in my application with Spring?

Tags: spring, sms, jms, jmstemplate

I wanna send SMS with JMS and Spring ,How can I do this ?
Could you give me tutorial or sample ,may be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all read [this](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jms.html). It is important that you first under stand the beans that are required and there roles.

If your searching for samples you need to find out what JMS technology your going to be using: 
`Tibco`, `MQ` etc. If this a test your going to run locally then `ActiveMQ` can get you up and running quickly:

[MQ Tutorial 101](http://activemq.apache.org/spring-support.html)

Comment: Ok. I understood you, I try to ask this. I have to send lots of SMS and Mail to users bringing data from database,How can I configure this problem on Spring ?Can I use JMS ?

Comment: Cant really add more than @Udo Held
has already said. JMS is primarily used for more than ona java application to exchange information via a jms provider. It will not send sms or mail for you so as mentioned a third party will be required

Answer (score 5):

Before starting JMS and Spring you should probably check if it would work out at all.

Unless you have a JMS-to-SMS gateway programming won't help at all. First you have to find a reseller or provider for your SMS service. Afterwards check what APIs they provide.

If they happen to provide a JMS gateway start reading the [Spring JMS manual](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jms.html).

You would probably need some JMSs provider as well. Check [MQ](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/integration/wmq/) or some smaller implementation like [ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/).